# Raspberry pi4 + Lineage OS + bluetooth headset Dont work

Tags: bluetooth, android

hello  im having some problem to use a headset bluetooth on a raspberry.
in you tube i can hear the sound perfectly
but in Linphone ( a softphone app or any other softphone ) i can hear and talk anything. i can hear the dial button sound but in a call my headset dont transmit sounds or receive any sound from the other person are talking.

can some one help me please?

Comment: Please contact the developer of the used LineageOS custom ROM in case of problems. LineageOS in Raspberry is very experimental and thus we can't help you here.

Comment: ok thank you. i will look for help